# Reboot Windows 8 on second screen; first screen laptop is broken

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display, reboot

The laptop has a broken screen. I got this fixed by hooking on a second screen. Now looking at the laptop, I found it too slow, so I did a clean reboot of Windows 8. It started but the second screen stayed black. The broken screen lights up (but it's shattered, so you can't see anything). Now I'm stuck; I can't see anything for configuration. I've tried win+ page up/down, shft + win+ arrow left/right.

Can anyone help?

Comment: how you have connected your second screen. and i think it is problem of os start windows 8 in safe mode. for going into safe mode press f8 while windows boots.

Comment: Windows 7 & 8, they detect the screen on booting, if you're using HDMI, then Windows will detected automatically, just plug it while your system is turned off, and then turn on your system. You won't have problem to do that unless if the HDMI driver is not installed on your system.